# No module named psycopg2._psycopg2 on Google Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, psycopg2, google-cloud-sql

I have a Google Cloud Function that uses Google Cloud SQL through psycopg2. I have psycopg2 in my requirements.txt but once the service updates I get the error `No module named psycopg2._psycopg2`.

Is this a problem with psycopg2's C libraries running in the [Cloud Function's environment](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/python-system-packages)? How do I fix this?

#### main.py

```
import psycopg2

def postgres_demo(request):
    return "hi"
```

#### requirements.txt

```
psycopg2==2.8.2
```

#### serverless.yml

```
service: gcf-python-v2

provider:
    name: google
    stage: dev
    runtime: python37
    region: us-central1
    project: my-project
    credentials: ~/.gcloud/keyfile.json

plugins:
    - serverless-google-cloudfunctions
    - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
    pythonRequirements:
        pythonBin: python3

package:
    exclude:
        - node_modules/**
        - .gitignore
        - .git/**

functions:
    second:
        handler: postgres_demo
        events:
            - http: path
```

#### Running `serverless deploy` always results in:

```
Deployment failed: RESOURCE_ERROR

 {"ResourceType":"cloudfunctions.v1beta2.function","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":"Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file main.py can't be loaded.\nDid you list all required modules in requirements.txt?\nDetailed stack trace: Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py\", line 305, in check_or_load_user_function\n    _function_handler.load_user_function()\n  File \"/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py\", line 184, in load_user_function\n    spec.loader.exec_module(main)\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 728, in exec_module\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed\n  File \"/user_code/main.py\", line 1, in <module>\n    import psycopg2\n  File \"/user_code/psycopg2/__init__.py\", line 50, in <module>\n    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'\n"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by removing `python-serverless-requirements` altogether and using the serverless `package` option to make sure only `main.py` and `requirements.txt` were included in the zip file.

Google cloud installs the packages in requirements.txt itself so you don't need a serverless plugin. Google cloud also has the necessary C libraries for psycopg2.